# How hard would it be to compile the linux kernel using MSVC?

Tags: c, visual-c++, kernel

I know linux kernel is written using "GNU C" instead of standard C.

I just wonder how hard (man-years) would it be to compile it using MSVC (say 2022).

It seems linux is using GNU C extensions with macros, so not so hard if somehow someone ports these macros?

Comment: does MSVC even support the ability to output the needed file format?

Comment: 2022 man-years sounds about right!

Comment: clang and intel both have the gcc extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has posted it, check out this kernel.org page:

[Minimal requirements to compile the Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/changes.html#minimal-requirements-to-compile-the-kernel)

Read the requirements.  Then all you have to do is to estimate the effort needed to port the minimal prerequisite packages shown here to the MSVC environment.  Also, because of this quote from the page:

> Again, keep in mind that this list assumes you are already
> functionally running a Linux kernel.

you will also need to port MSVC itself to your functional Linux kernel environment (assuming Microsoft licensing will permit that).